# Actually, how many kind of database are there?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I am new at database administrator, i just want to mapping actually, how many kind of database are there. I made this map, i want to ask, Is it true ?

Simply, I wanna to make map likes Historical Tree / Genealogy of database.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VwAhmXH2OVbm8yTm9ld1oxY1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have Oracle and DB2 under NO-SQL databases -- just highly amusing because Oracle and IBM pretty much invented *relational* database technology.  I think you need to learn what the headers mean before attempting to classify anything.

Answer (score 0):

**[cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)** and  **[hbase](https://hbase.apache.org/)** are column store databases. I think these are missing in NoSql databases and ArangoDB is a multi-model database which supports Key-value, document storage and graph

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion Dileep Kumar. Hmm, it's pretty complex to mapping. Any suggestion for mapping this to be familly tree of database ?

Comment: Cassandra is not a column store database. It is a key-value database with dynamic columns support. [HP Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/get-started-vertica/architecture/#Column) is a column-oriented database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010225/why-many-refer-to-cassandra-as-a-column-oriented-database